# Modifying jQuery sliding underline in navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following sliding underline element under my navigation. The idea is that when a link is hovered, the underline slides over to that element. See codepen:
https://codepen.io/lucasengnz/pen/eQaQxy

The issue I have is that when the nav is not being used I want the underline to slide back to the first link. I have no clue on how to do this, as I am quite new to using `javascript` and `jQuery`. Any pointers?

```js
$(".underline-nav").css("width", $("#one").width());
$(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $("#one").css("margin-left"));

$('nav a').hover(function() {
  $(".underline-nav").css("width", $(this).width());
  $(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $(this).css("margin-left"));
  var position = $(this).position();
  $(".underline-nav").css("left", position.left);
})
```

```css
.underline-nav {
  background: tomato;
  height: .25rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.8em;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

nav {
  font-size: 1.85em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1vh;
}

#one {
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 3vw;
}

.floatright a {
  margin-left: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav>
    <a id="one" href="#">one</a>
    <div class="floatright">
      <a id="tt" href="#">two</a>
      <a href="#">three</a>
      <a href="#">four</a>
      <a href="#">five</a>
    </div>
    <div class="underline-nav">
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by `not being used`? When the users takes the mouse away from the nav menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    $(".underline-nav").css("width", $("#one").width());
    $(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $("#one").css("margin-left"));
    var unav = $(".underline-nav");
    $('nav a').mouseover(function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        unav.css({
          "width": $(this).width(),
          "margin-left": $(this).css("margin-left"),
          "left": position.left
        });
    })
    $('nav').mouseleave(function() {
      var firstChild = $(this).find('a:first-child');
      var position = firstChild.position();
        unav.css({
          "width": firstChild.width(),
          "margin-left": firstChild.css("margin-left"),
          "left": position.left
        });
    })
```

Comment: this is excellent my friend. Is there a way I can change the duration?

Comment: Yeah you can do that in your css by changing `transition:all ease 0.7s;` for underline-nav class

Answer (score 1):

> [.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be
>   executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

So you can underline the first element when mouse pointer leaves the element.

```js
$(".underline-nav").css("width", $("#one").width());
$(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $("#one").css("margin-left"));

$('nav a').hover(function() {
  $(".underline-nav").css("width", $(this).width());
  $(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $(this).css("margin-left"));
  var position = $(this).position();
  $(".underline-nav").css("left", position.left);
},
function () {
  // on leave , revert to first
  $(".underline-nav").css("width", $("#one").width());
  $(".underline-nav").css("margin-left", $("#one").css("margin-left"));
  $(".underline-nav").css("left", $("#one").position().left);
}
)
```

```css
.underline-nav {
  background: tomato;
  height: .25rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.8em;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

nav {
  font-size: 1.85em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1vh;
}

#one {
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 3vw;
}

.floatright a {
  margin-left: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <nav>
    <a id="one" href="#">one</a>
    <div class="floatright">
      <a id="tt" href="#">two</a>
      <a href="#">three</a>
      <a href="#">four</a>
      <a href="#">five</a>
    </div>
    <div class="underline-nav">
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```